# Create a main method in tcl?

Tags: scripting, tcl, program-entry-point, tk-toolkit

I want to centralize the execution of various methods by calling them from a single method, like a main method in java..is there a way to do this in tcl?

I've looked everywhere for the answer but so far no luck. An another way to go about this is to setup flags within the functions so the code block is only executed when the flag has a specific value but this is a tedious process since there a lot of procedures in my program.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Example (pseudo-code):

```
func1 () {...}
func2 () {...}

main method () {
  int a, b
  func1(a)
  func2(b)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tcl can be seen as a scripting language. The body of the Tcl script is the main method. Thus, you don't really need a main method. Calling procedures from procedures is standard functionality:

```
proc func1 {} {
    puts A
}

proc func2  {} {
    puts B
}

proc Main {} {
    func1
    func2
}

Main
```

[↓](http://ideone.com/90vuIx)

```
A
B
```

`Main` has to be called explicitly in order for `func1` and `func2` be executed.

Just putting the `Main` contents into the [script body](http://ideone.com/uNJOxo) produces the same result

Comment: I tend to use this strategy myself. Either pass `$argv` to Main, as demonstrated by Donal, or add `global argc argv` to the top of the Main proc.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing something `main`-like is to use a lambda application. If you're doing this, it is often helpful to pass in the script arguments.

```
# Usual stuff at the top of a script
pacakge require Tcl 8.5
package require pkgABC
package require pkgDEF

proc GHI {} { ... }

apply {{a b args} {
    # This part now works like main() in C or Java or ...
}} {*}$argv
```